# String with leading and trailing whitespaces on using gettext() method with MicrosoftWebDriver and Edge browser + selenium automation

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

Tried verifying the label of a field using MicrosoftWebDriver on Edge browser by identifying the element then using "text()" method to retrieve the label.

expect(driver.find_element(***).text).to eq "label"

## I'm sure i have identified the element properly.

expected: "Labels"
got:      "Labels "

Note: Found an existing issue logged against the same. But the status is unknown.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5569343/

Answer (score 0):

"Labels " is what you found inside the elements.

Sometimes developers put spaces for better UI.

for your test case scenario you can test in two ways if requirement is not rigid about spaces.

1. expect "Labels " as requirement. *if developer will change number of spaces test case will fail.*
2. trim result text. *test case will not get affected by changes in leading or trailing spaces.*

Comment: I found the text of the element in console i.e. Labels(no space).

Comment: Moreover, the same code works fine with chrome and ie drivers.

Comment: are you getting that label by id?

Comment: There must be a better explanation for why Edge has this behavior with WebDriver. We're running into the same issue, and can't figure out why every string has a trailing space when those spaces don't exist in the element in the browser or when using WebDriver with other browsers.